# Problem uploading member image in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco8

I am working with member API in Umbraco 8 and i am trying to upload the image when registering. After i register member and open member profile in backoffice i see this:
[image]

This is my Coontroller

```
    public class RegisterController : SurfaceController
{
    // GET: Register
    public ActionResult Register(Models.RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return CurrentUmbracoPage();

        var memberService = Services.MemberService;

        if (memberService.GetByEmail(model.Email) != null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "A member with that email alredy exists");
            return CurrentUmbracoPage();
        }

        var member = memberService.CreateMemberWithIdentity(model.Email, model.Email, model.Name, "bMEMembers");

        member.SetValue("companyName", model.CompanyName );
        member.SetValue("avatar", model.Avatar);


        memberService.SavePassword(member, model.Password);
        Members.Login(model.Email, model.Password);

        memberService.Save(member);

        return Redirect("/");
    }
}
```

Model:

```
        public HttpPostedFileBase Avatar { get; set; }
```

View:

```
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Avatar)
    <input type="file" name="Avatar" />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Avatar)

    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Create" />
```

Anybody could help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It's normal to appear because `Avatar` is an object (exactly: `HttpPostedFileBase`), and `LabelFor` will display object namespace.

Take a look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.labelfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

and see that there is an overload for that method:

```
public static System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel,TValue> (this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel> html, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TModel,TValue>> expression, string labelText, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object> htmlAttributes);
```

you can use like:

`@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Avatar, "Avatar", null);`

---

**or more beauty way:**

```
[DisplayName("Avatar")]
public HttpPostedFileBase Avatar { get; set; }
```

and leave your CSHTML code:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Avatar)
```

Comment: Forgive me if iI dont understund, but if I add [DisplayName("Avatar")] to my model i still got the same result.

Comment: Try first option then

Comment: unfortunately i got the same result

Comment: Then problem is somewhere else

Comment: I have tried this code in Umbraco 7 and its working there, but not in Umbraco 8

Comment: Then Umbraco 8 override that method...did you open a ticked on their github ?

Comment: No, I didnt. I wasnt sure is it my mistake or their.